# Returning Handmade XML from a Simple EJB

Tags: xml, ejb

I've create an EJB in Eclipse with a method that returns String.

The String is an XML fragment made from a DOM Document.

When I invoke the EJB as a web service, the String is correct, but it gets CDATA tags added around it.  How can I avoid this and get the raw XML in there, directly, instead?

Thank you

```
@WebService(serviceName = "XService", portName = "XPort", targetNamespace = "http://here.com/x/ejb")
@Stateless(name = "X", mappedName = "ejb/XJNDI")
@SOAPBinding
   (
     style = SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT,
     use = SOAPBinding.Use.LITERAL,
     parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE
    )
public class XEJB implements X
{
```

public String  complex(int input) 
 {
   // builds and returns some XML as a String
        }
    }

Comment: Is there a @WebMethod annotated method that you'd care to show

Comment: The class "implements X", X would include an @remote with a method that returns a String.  The hand made XML then gets wrapped in a CDATA.  

I gave up on changing this and went ahead with returning an instance of a class with getters and setters instead (the more traditional approach).  

In either case, there's no @WebMethod tag used.